# Elasticsearch performance difference between ‘must’ and ‘must_not’

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.4

I wanted to know the performance difference between using `must` clause and `must_not`.
I am getting different timings trying from both of them.
Suppose I have 10 groups, and I want to make 5 groups accessible to a user while 5 are excluded.
So, I have two ways of using my query:

I can use `must` clause inside a boolean query, and do `must: ['1', '2' ,'3', '4', '5']`.
I can use `must_not` clause inside a boolean query again, and do `must_not:['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']`.

I have not provided many details here because I just want to know more about the performance wise difference in using these two terms.
I read about the Boolean query in the ES document, and it said the scoring is ignored in the `must_not` clause, although I have not yet understood how scoring is performed in the Lucene index.
But I am getting some timing differences, and `must_not` is taking longer time than `must` and was curious to post about it.

Note: Currently using, *Elasticsearch version:2.4.4*, and upgrading it is not possible at the moment.
Can anyone please explain the difference or explain both of the clauses in detail?
Open to any kind of suggestions and answers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many docs do you have and are they evenly distributed among your 10 groups? If not, what would you say the distribution looks like?

Answer (score 0):

`must` clause is potentially more efficient because it can utilize the inverted index.

The internal implementation is more like

```
If _searched_keyword_ in inverted_hash
THEN RETRIEVE inverted_hash[_searched_keyword_ ]
```

`must_not` is more costly as the inverted index is not helpful.